# Русские буквы в комментариях CSS

Tags: css, gitlab

Заливаю лабу в `gitlab`, но там не отображаются комментарии русскими буквами в CSS файле, в `html` файле все нормально. Как сделать чтобы русские буквы отображались в комментариях в файле CSS?

Вот что я вижу в `gitlab`:

```
width: 50%; /*        .     :      ,     50%   .*/
```

Comment: Попробуйте преобразовать кодировку файла в UTF-8 без BOM и попробовать снова